# passing an numpy array to a numpy array of function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm writing a class with the purpose to solve system of differential equations, the class is constructed using a composition with one other class named rhs (right hand side) that should represent the function of a given differential problem.
In case of a system of ode this rhs.function became an array of function ! (for this reason I'm also using a vector for the solution) the problem that I have is how to pass the array of the solution to the function, I going to show the code here,
the class Rhs is:

```
 class Rhs:
   '''
      class to define a differential problems 
      contains the dy/dt function and the initial value 
      in order to close the ode problem
   '''
   solution = None

   def __init__(self, fnum : np.ndarray , t0: np.float, tf: np.float, y0 : np.array, n: int , fanal = None ):
      '''   
         Input : 
            - fnum : Function f(t,y(t)) = dy/dt (numeric)
            - 
            - Initial Time t0 
            - Final Time tf
            - Initial value u0_i(t0) = y0_i(t0)  
      '''
      self.func = fnum
      Rhs.solution  = fanal
      self.t0   = t0
      self.tf   = tf
      self.n    = n
      self.u0   = y0


   def createArray(self):
      '''   
         Create the Array time and f(time) 
         - the time array can be create now 
         - the solution array can be just initialize with the IV (array)
      ''' 
      self.t = np.linspace(self.t0, self.tf, self.n )
      self.u = np.array([self.u0  for i in range(self.n) ])


      return self.t,self.u   

   def f(self,ti,ui):
       return  np.array([function(ti,ui) for function in self.func])
```

this class is instantiate in the main file, (`problem = Rhs(... args ...)`) 
then passed to initalize the class Euler reported here :

```
 class Explicit:
   '''
      Solve the ODE using first order Foward difference
      Explicit first order Method (Euler)  
   '''
   solved = False  # True if the method 'solve' was called without error 
   def __init__(self, dydt: rhs.Rhs, save : bool=True, _print: bool=False,  filename : str=None):
      ''' 
         Initialize the Foward Euler solver 
            - dydt (to the super class) : RHS problem dy/dt = f(t,y(t)) t(0)=y0 
            - save : if True returns the 2 vector time and u = du/dt 
      '''
      self._print = _print
      self.save   = save 
      self.file   = filename
      self.dydt   = dydt
      self.dt     = (dydt.tf-dydt.t0)/dydt.n



   def solve(self):
      self.time, self.u = self.dydt.createArray() 
      for i in range(len(self.time)-1):
          #for j in range(len(self.u[0,:])):
              self.u[i+1] = self.u[i] + self.dt*self.dydt.f(self.time[i],self.u[i])


      Explicit.solved = True 

      if self._print:
          with open(self.file,'w') as f:
              for i in range(len(self.time)):      
                 f.write('%.4f %4f %4f %4f\n' %(self.time[i] ,self.u[i,0], self.u[i,1], self.u[i,2]))

      if self.save:
         return self.time,self.u
```

and finally the simply main function :

```
func1 = lambda t,u : 10   * (u[1] - u[0])
func2 = lambda t,u : 28   * u[0] - u[1] - u[0] * u[2]  
func3 = lambda t,u : -8/3 * u[2] + u[0]*u[1]
def main():

   func = np.array([func1,func2,func3])

   y0 = np.array([1.,0.,0.]) 

   problem3   = rhs.Rhs(func,0.0,100.0,y0,1000) 
   t,u       = problem3.createArray()

   fwdeuler_p1 = euler.Explicit(problem3 , True,_print=True, filename ='lorentz.dat')
   fet,feu = fwdeuler_p1.solve()
```

I hope that the syntax used inside the lambda function it's clear : each one of this represent a function in which the u[N] is the unknown function.

I've developed a class hierarchy in C++ and works fine (if you are interested [can find it here](https://github.com/drudox/SystemDiffEquation/blob/master/Euler/ForwardEulerSolver.H)).

the error that I got with the python programs is this :

```
 drive.py:31: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  func2 = lambda t,u : 28   * u[0] - u[1] - u[0] * u[2]
drive.py:32: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  func3 = lambda t,u : -8/3 * u[2] + u[0]*u[1]
drive.py:31: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  func2 = lambda t,u : 28   * u[0] - u[1] - u[0] * u[2]
/home/marco/Programming/Python/Numeric/OdeSystem/euler.py:77: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
  self.u[i+1] = self.u[i] + self.dt*self.dydt.f(self.time[i],self.u[i])
```

**EDIT** really sorry ! Correct the mistake now is correct.

**EDIT** I solved make the time step smaller :) thanks to everybody that try to help me

Comment: first problem: func and problem3 don't exist, the code you provided is not the code which gives this error. the problem lies surely in the y0 you're really using. second problem: you never use t in your lambdas, so your code may not work as you expect